# App crashing when launching from AppStore or TestFlight but working fine elseways

Tags: ios, swift, crash, testflight, crash-reports

My application update has been rejected. Into the rejection message, they wrote "Application crashes at launch". I then tried my application but couldn't make it crash. So I used TestFlight and noticed that when I was launched my app from TestFlight or AppStore, it was crashing at launch. But if I launch my app normally, it does work without any crashes. The thing is this bug occurred since iOS 10 update. Now my application on store also crashes when launched from AppStore while it was working fine 2 weeks go.

Apple sent me a crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: 001969F1-F275-4AC3-AFE1-E0426957B702
CrashReporter Key:   5ad9695e945a7d5eb5d61fd18d1c3989ccd155b4
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             MyApp [400]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/644423A4-EFE7-41B1-99D9-47B46338A6E2/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:          com.MyApp.com
Version:             20160527 (2.7.9)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.MyApp.com [451]


Date/Time:           2016-09-22 11:19:22.6893 -0700
Launch Time:         2016-09-22 11:19:22.4164 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.0.1 (14A403)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000010008a864
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0  MyApp                         0x1000efd3c specialized AppDelegate.application(UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions : [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool (AppDelegate.swift:218)
1  MyApp                         0x1000ed310 @objc AppDelegate.application(UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions : [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool (AppDelegate.swift)
2  UIKit                          0x19888c42c <redacted> + 400
3  UIKit                          0x198a9cb70 <redacted> + 3524
4  UIKit                          0x198aa28e0 <redacted> + 1656
5  UIKit                          0x198ab7080 <redacted> + 48
6  UIKit                          0x198a9f8c4 <redacted> + 168
7  FrontBoardServices             0x1945798bc <redacted> + 36
8  FrontBoardServices             0x194579728 <redacted> + 176
9  FrontBoardServices             0x194579ad0 <redacted> + 56
10 CoreFoundation                 0x192986278 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
11 CoreFoundation                 0x192985bc0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 524
12 CoreFoundation                 0x1929837c0 __CFRunLoopRun + 804
13 CoreFoundation                 0x1928b2048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
14 UIKit                          0x1988855dc <redacted> + 608
15 UIKit                          0x198880360 UIApplicationMain + 208
16 MyApp                         0x1000ee818 main (AppDelegate.swift:58)
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x1918945b8 (Missing)
```

There is 4 others threads but this one is the one crashing so I did not copy the rest. I did some research and even though I did notice my crash log wasn't fully translated (for some strange reason since I have all dsyms but whatever), I did manage to understand that I was crashing on line 217 (tell me if I'm wrong). I know that SIGTRAP are most of time NSExceptions being thrown. The line itself is:

```
let api = MyAppAPI.instance
```

The instance is a singleton. My guess is that something into the instance creation is failing. Here is the code:

```
static var instance: MyAppAPI = {
    return Singleton.instance
}()

class MyAppAPI: Manager {
struct Singleton {
    static var configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration = {
        var configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        let version = NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("CFBundleShortVersionString") as? String ?? ""
        configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = [
            "Accept": "application/vnd.MyApp.api+json, application/json;q=0.9",
            "User-Agent": "MyApp iOS/\(version)",
            "X-API-Version": "1.0.1"
        ]

        return configuration
        }()

    static var instance = MyAppAPI(configuration: configuration)
    static var baseURL : NSURL! = nil
}
```

I'm so desperate about this error, I did try a few things that did not work out. Am I looking into the right place ? Is there anyone with a solution ? Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. I'm willing to gift anyone that can find me the solution or help me find the solution !

Comment: crash report needs symbolicating.

Comment: Add altert start from appdelegate to further Viewcontrollers you will find issue

Comment: I'll try an alternative push to other views, thanks. About the symbolicating, I did wrote something about it in the question and I already did translate half of the crash report. Do I need to translate everything since the part crashing is already translated ?

Comment: Bryan, do you find the answer? I have the same problem, Thanks!

Comment: For me, it is `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution of my problem.

As expected it was coming from `func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool`

Inside the function I had `let userInfo = launchOpts[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as! NSDictionary`.

I changed it to `let userInfo = launchOpts[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? NSDictionary` and then checked `if userInfo != nil` to make all the code running `userInfo`into the bracket.

If it helps anyone or if anyone is struggling with this issue, check all yours `!` and swap these to `?` if needed (on `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`) since launching from TestFlight/AppStore seems to have different options than from installed application (just a guess, not pro enough to claim it).

Comment: How did you find that was the case, since you can't debug it? Did you device crash logs / crash reporting tool isolate it down to the line # this was called on?

Comment: I did debug it through AlertView if I remember correctly. I printed logs in specific points, which helped me debug this !

Comment: this is the best thing i've read all week thank you

Comment: Hi Bryan, I am getting same crashlogs from apple side. Can you please help me out how would I get a correct error. Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are getting a crash from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions on AppDelegate ?