# How to interprate a application revision using itunes

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, app-store-connect

I'm just uploading an update of my swift/xcode project.

But, in the revision I get my application as rejected with the messsage:

> We were unable to review your app as it crashed on launch. We have
>   attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.
>
> Please revise your app and test it on a device while connected to an
>   IPv6 network (all apps must support IPv6) to ensure it will launch
>   without crashing.

I already tested the application in the emulators and physical devices and it's working good. But in the crash log says:

```
{"app_name":"SMD","timestamp":"2017-02-22 13:44:46.73 -0800","app_version":"1.8","slice_uuid":"22698b95-8afb-3280-95bcxxxxx","adam_id":0,"build_version":"8","bundleID":"com.bsn.xxx.xxx.xxx","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 10.2.1 (14D27)","incident_id":"9CC007C2-1E44-xxxx-xxx-xxxx","name":"SMD"}
Incident Identifier: 9CC007C2-1E44-xxx-xxxx-xxxx
CrashReporter Key:   c85f7089c245d2e6a851615f5e8862f0391xxxx
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             SMD [1003]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A50BBAAD-A1E0-4992-97C1-01B14C4F7DF1/SMD.app/SMD
Identifier:          com.bsn.sm.SMD.SMD
Version:             8 (1.8)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.bsn.sm.SMD.SMD [864]


Date/Time:           2017-02-22 13:44:46.6041 -0800
Launch Time:         2017-02-22 13:44:45.6077 -0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.2.1 (14D27)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000100caa4a4
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000100caa4a4 0x100b68000 + 1320100
1   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000100caa4a4 0x100b68000 + 1320100
2   SMD                 0x000000010008a160 0x100080000 + 41312
3   Alamofire                       0x00000001007bba14 0x100780000 + 244244
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001877821fc 0x187781000 + 4604
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001877821bc 0x187781000 + 4540
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000187786d68 0x187781000 + 23912
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001888a6810 0x1887c9000 + 907280
8   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001888a43fc 0x1887c9000 + 898044
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001887d22b8 0x1887c9000 + 37560
10  GraphicsServices                0x000000018a286198 0x18a27a000 + 49560
11  UIKit                           0x000000018e8127fc 0x18e798000 + 501756
12  UIKit                           0x000000018e80d534 0x18e798000 + 480564
13  SMD                 0x00000001000ac360 0x100080000 + 181088
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001877b55b8 0x1877b1000 + 17848

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001878c7a88 0x1878a8000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018798b344 0x18798a000 + 4932
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018798ad8c 0x18798a000 + 3468

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001878c7a88 0x1878a8000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018798b344 0x18798a000 + 4932
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018798ad8c 0x18798a000 + 3468

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001878c7a88 0x1878a8000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018798b344 0x18798a000 + 4932
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018798ad8c 0x18798a000 + 3468

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001878a9188 0x1878a8000 + 4488
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001878a8ff8 0x1878a8000 + 4088
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001888a65d0 0x1887c9000 + 906704
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001888a41ec 0x1887c9000 + 897516
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001887d22b8 0x1887c9000 + 37560
5   Foundation                      0x000000018930f26c 0x189303000 + 49772
6   Foundation                      0x000000018932fdd0 0x189303000 + 183760
7   UIKit                           0x000000018f186c38 0x18e798000 + 10415160
8   Foundation                      0x000000018940ce68 0x189303000 + 1089128
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018798d850 0x18798a000 + 14416
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018798d760 0x18798a000 + 14176
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018798ad94 0x18798a000 + 3476

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001878c7a88 0x1878a8000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018798b344 0x18798a000 + 4932
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018798ad8c 0x18798a000 + 3468

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001878a9188 0x1878a8000 + 4488
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001878a8ff8 0x1878a8000 + 4088
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001888a65d0 0x1887c9000 + 906704
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001888a41ec 0x1887c9000 + 897516
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001887d22b8 0x1887c9000 + 37560
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000188fd7a70 0x188ef8000 + 916080
6   Foundation                      0x000000018940ce68 0x189303000 + 1089128
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018798d850 0x18798a000 + 14416
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018798d760 0x18798a000 + 14176
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018798ad94 0x18798a000 + 3476

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001878c7a88 0x1878a8000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018798b160 0x18798a000 + 4448
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018798ad8c 0x18798a000 + 3468

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018798ad88 0x18798a000 + 3464

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x000000010123c380   x1: 0x00000001700f1f80   x2: 0x0000000000000008   x3: 0x000000018790d22c
    x4: 0x000000000000000e   x5: 0x0000000000000020   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000bf0
    x8: 0x00000001700f3680   x9: 0x00000001700f3680  x10: 0x0000000000000001  x11: 0xbaddc0dedeadbead
   x12: 0x0000010000000100  x13: 0x206e6120676e6970  x14: 0x6c616e6f6974704f  x15: 0x000a65756c617620
   x16: 0x00000001878fd6b0  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000
   x20: 0x0000000000000002  x21: 0x0000000000000039  x22: 0x00000001003a7160  x23: 0x0000000000000002
   x24: 0x000000000000000b  x25: 0x00000001003a719a  x26: 0xffffffffffffffff  x27: 0x0000000170469f40
   x28: 0x0000000002ffffff   fp: 0x000000016fd7e760   lr: 0x0000000100caa4a4
    sp: 0x000000016fd7e720   pc: 0x0000000100caa4a4 cpsr: 0x20000000
```

How I can find my issues there?

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39788965/app-crashing-when-launching-from-appstore-or-testflight-but-working-fine-elseway

Comment: Please update your question with your*application(didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) code! I think what @ebby94 is saying may be correct, and if so, this would be quite helpful for everyone to search on. Even if you have *no* code in there, that would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Apple's documentation

> Swift code will terminate with this exception type if an unexpected
> condition is encountered at runtime such as:
>
> a non-optional type with a nil value
>
> a failed forced type conversion

You might be accidentally unwrapping an optional with nil value or maybe doing something wrong in the type conversion(Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40427931/3066450)).

For IPv6 compatibility, you can go through Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1) about it.